# Animate Replacing viewControllers for UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a menu that allows users to switch between view stacks. What I'd like to do is have the UINavigationController switch from one stack to the next with the slide animation.

So, to add one view to the current stack, I know I can do this:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
```

Which will slide the view onto the stack, animated.

And I know I can do this

```
self.navigationController!.viewControllers = newControllersStack
```

But that's not animated and feels hacky as it just injects into the stack flow without any proper flow. What I want to do is this

```
self.navigationController!.changeViewControllers(newControllersStack, animated: true)
```

Is there a way to do this? I've looked into a tab bar, but I'd have to hide the tabs (using a side menu for navigation) and even then, it animates transitions between UINavigationControllers, not views inside of a single nav controller.

Comment: What about `UINavigationController.setViewControllers(_:animated:)`?

Comment: This is an antipattern. When in a navigation stack, users expect to be able to traverse the stack in the same order they reached the current controller. I would not suggest replacing the stack in such a manner.

Comment: @LeoNatan Well shit. How'd I miss that. Add it as an answer and I'll accept. That looks like exactly what I need. In my case, this makes sense. It's a new navigation stack, similar to a tab controller, when they select something from the side menu.

Comment: Cool. Added as an answer.

Comment: Will accept in 5 @LeoNatan. You got to it so fast I haven't reached the accepted timeframe for accepting an answer yet.

Comment: Haha, no worries. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UINavigationController.setViewControllers(_:animated:)`.